# Boolean query for pandas column names containing a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'reports_1': [3, 42, 25, 25, 25], 
        'reports_2': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I want to do a boolean query to ask if a column name contains a string (i.e. a partial match):

Pseudo-code example:

```
For c in df.columns:
    if df.columns[c] contains 'reports':
        print('yay')
    else:
        print('boo')
```

Pseudo-code output I want:

```
Boo
Yay
Yay
```

Comment: your pseudo code is so close to the correct code, did you try it?

Comment: Also what are you asking for exactly, code that does what you want or if there is some pandas method to achieve what you want. At the moment your pseudo code is pure python and is a simple task to do

Comment: It is pseudo code because "if df.columns[c] contains 'reports':" is not valid. There is no "contains" query

Comment: Well this would generate a boolean series: `pd.Series(df.columns).str.contains('reports')` is that what you want?

Comment: I'll undelete my answer so you can see what I did

Answer (score 3):

we can iterate over the columns and just test if the string is in the column string:

```
In [14]:

data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'reports_1': [3, 42, 25, 25, 25], 
        'reports_2': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for col in df:
    if 'reports' in col:
        print('yay')
    else:
        print('boo')
boo
yay
yay
```

another way would be to create a series from the columns and use the vectorised `str` method `contains`:

```
In [33]:

pd.Series(df.columns).str.contains('reports').apply( lambda x: 'yay' if x == True else 'boo')
Out[33]:
0    boo
1    yay
2    yay
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.columns.map(lambda x: "reports" in x and 'yay' or 'boo')
```

Comment: `lambda x: 'yay' if 'reports' in x else 'boo'` is better style than the old-fashioned and/or hack.